# Python error __init__() missing 1 required positional argument 'days'

Tags: python

I'm getting an error specifically when I run this code as part of the overall program:

py

```
pars = dict(
    pop_size=200e3, 
    pop_infected=75, 
    beta=0.012, 
    pop_type='hybrid',
    start_day='2020-02-10', 
    end_day='2020-11-29',
)       

trace_probs = dict(h=0.9, s=0.7, w=0.7, c=0.3) 
trace_time = dict(h=0, s=1, w=1, c= 3) 
interventions = [
    cv.clip_edges(start_day='2020-03-26', end_day=None, changes={'s' : 0.0})
]
```

The error that results is:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'days'.
```

I'm not understanding why this is?  Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that cv.clip_edges() requires a parameter called "days". Maybe you can use your start and end dates to calculate the total number of days. Then, place the number as the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for replying and your suggestion. I don’t understand why it’s asking for a parameter called ‘days’. The intervention have specific duration of days and so do you mean to created a parameter that have the total number of days instead of having a start and end date in the cv.clip_edges line? If so, I’ll try that! Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately, although it worked, when I tried to graph, python had an issue with converting the total number of days into dates: ValueError: Was unable to convert "58" to a date using the formats:
date           : %Y-%m-%d
date-alpha     : %Y-%b-%d
date-numeric   : %Y%m%d
datetime       : %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
datetime-alpha : %Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S
default        : %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
ctime          : %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y. <---I wonder if I can do cumulative time instead?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly because I don't know what this clip_edges is, perhaps it would help if you told me the package it is from?